# JavaFX - How to make VBox children grow with VBox parent

Tags: javafx, parent, scaling, vbox

```
VBox classBox = new VBox();
className = new Text("defaultClass");
classBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
classBox.getChildren().add(className);
classBox.getStyleClass().add(VM_BOXES);

variablesBox = new VBox();
variablesBox.getStyleClass().add(VM_BOXES);

methodsBox = new VBox();
methodsBox.getStyleClass().add(VM_BOXES);

this.getChildren().add(classBox);
this.getChildren().add(variablesBox);
this.getChildren().add(methodsBox);

this.getStyleClass().add(VM_BOXES);
```

Hi, I have a class that extends `VBox` and has three children that are also `VBox`es. I have written a method where I can resize the class and make it bigger/smaller. When I make it larger, the VBoxes inside of it do not scale with the parent. I am not sure if it is scaling horizontally or not but It is not scaling vertically. I tried searching online for solutions but cannot find any. Any help is appreciated, thanks [image]

Here is a picture to visual the problem

Answer (score 7):

You have to set the vertical grow constraints for the `VBoxes`:

```
VBox.setVgrow(box1, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: sorry, if youre still there, if you can tell me how to do the same thing for labels within those children VBoxes, I would would be really grateful.

Comment: Set the vGrow to your Label as well, and set its maxHeight sufficiently high

Comment: @jns: talking about boxes inside boxes, IMHO the line you wrote can be misleading, I personally needed some trials and errors to get it right.
 - VBox is the name of the javaFX class (setVgrow is a static method)
 - box1 is the instance of the object you want to grow, so it should be replaced by label1 to answer your second question